# Memory leak - Returning without disposing "new CheckBox(...)"

Tags: c#, winforms, memory-leaks

```
protected override void SetValueFromControl()
{
CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox();

if (this.comboBox_Meta.SelectedItem != null)
{
    if (this.comboBox_Meta.SelectedIndex != 1)
    {
        checkbox.Checked = true;
    }
    else
    {
       checkbox.Checked = false;
    }

    this.my_Helper.SetValueFromCheckBox("xxx", checkbox);
}
}
```

My ANT Profiler says there is a resource leak as following error

> Returning without disposing "new CheckBox(...)".

In My SetValueFromCheckBox method I am using the below condition.

```
some value = _checkbox.Checked;
```

Note: Now after helpful feedback from community I have added "using" and waiting for next build for error verification.

Comment: Unless `SetValueFromCheckBox` does so, why are you creating a `CheckBox` and not adding it to a form?

Comment: You create a checkbox, but you don't add it to the control tree. Isn't your code missing some parts?

Comment: And please, also add [asp.net], [winform] or [WPF] tag !

Comment: iShare, you still have not answered the question by Steve B. We get that you are using the object and its property, but the code can be re-written using a boolean variable instead. What is the necessity of creating a CheckBox UI Control ?

Answer (score 3):

No, the error means you should call `Dispose`.

or wrap it in a `using` block:

```
using (var chk = new CheckBox())
{
    // your code
} // at this line `Dispose` is called automatically, even in case of exception
```

Every Windows Forms control creates a bunch of handles etc. that are not freed automatically. Most of them are only created when the control is displayed so you *might* be ok without the dispose call but since the profiler does not know that it will complain. And it is a best practice to always dispose objects that implement `IDisposable` - you never know if the implementation will change and the object will create handles by itself.

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

Comment: this code has no sense.... why creating a checkbox if the checkbox is not used? This won't help the OP to understand why it occurs. It will only mask a real problem

Comment: @SteveB: Don't downvote - look at the OP's source code. Also, from Knagis' code it is not even clear whether the check box is unused. Within the `using` block it might be properly used.

Comment: +1 for the explanation of the Dispose pattern, but still an invalid answer I think

Answer (score 2):

It is a common misconception that setting things to `null` actually disposes of them. It does not. To dispose of the `CheckBox`, call its `Dispose` method. This is done automatically when you use the `using` statement as the others have suggested.

This, however, is not necessary when you actually add the control to the control tree! In that case the control will be disposed of when the form is disposed of.

Answer (score 0):

It means you should call dispose on it or use the using statement.

```
using(CheckBox checkbox = new CheckBox())
{

    if (this.comboBox_Meta.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        if (this.comboBox_Meta.SelectedIndex != 1)
        {
            checkbox.Checked = true;
        }
        else
        {
           checkbox.Checked = false;

        }

        this.my_Helper.SetValueFromCheckBox("xxx", checkbox);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the code that OP had posted. I just wrapped it in a using block. Also the checkbox variable is used in this call 'this.my_Helper.SetValueFromCheckBox("xxx", checkbox);'

Comment: @SteveB: It's not fair to downvote people based on the OP's code.

Comment: I think your answer will make more damages than it will helps. Removing the warning does not mean that the problem is solved. I truly believe that the OP has the be put on the correct way instead of hiding the problems.

Comment: I belive the fix is not just for the warning but also disposes the control object that is created within the code. Whether the OP choses to add this to their UI control tree or not, is their choice and also depends on the logic. Just because I believe controls shoudl be added to the form does not mean that is the only correct way.

Answer (score 0):

When you create dynamically control, you sould ultimately add the control to the control tree.

If you don't, there's no sense to create such control.

The direct side effect of not adding the control to the tree control is that you will miss the out of the box Dispose of the control tree. When a control is disposed (the form at the top level), of its child controls will be disposed recursively.

Other are suggesting to add a `using` statement, but I believe it's wrong. It will remove the warning, but the actual problem is that you are not working with the controls tree properly.

Comment: What if the user wants to use the control only in the code and not display it ? In such a case, the user will need to explicitly dispose it without having added it to the form or any controls within?

Comment: For the an object of the control to be used elsewhere... may be a class library expects an object of the UI control type, I may not have written that (poorly written and interfaced library) but i would need to use it for my current application.

Comment: Dont forget that even IF SetValueFromCheckbox would do something usefull with the Checkbox, it's not reached on all codepaths ...

Comment: If the OP justify this decision, I will remove the downvote. Let him a chance to precise his thoughts

Comment: Thanks steve, I will EDIT my post with more info